# How to avoid calling function in base class?

Tags: c++

I have two classes `A` and `B` like below, `B` have to inherit from `A`. The `classType()` function of class `B` is not provided, If call `B::classType()`, will get the class type of `A`. I would like to get a compiler error here instead of calling into the `classType()` function of class `A`. How do I do it?

In general, the sub classes of `A` should provide the function `classType()`, in case the author forgets to write the `classType()` function, it's best to report a compiler error. This is the purpose. Maybe, I can use `static_assert` in `TypeOf()` function.

```
class A
{
public:
    static const char* classType()
    {
        static const char* s_classType = "A";
        return s_classType;
    }
};

class B : public A
{
};

template <class T>
const char* TypeOf()
{
    return T::classType();
}

int main()
{
    const char* type = TypeOf<B>(); // I would like to get compiler error here, not get "A".
}
```

Comment: Prefer `std::string` to `const char*`.

Comment: `void main`?? -

Comment: Solution: replace `class B : public A` with `class B`.

Comment: @Evg, B needs to inherits form A in the case.

Comment: *the sub classes of `A` should provide the function `classType()`* - maybe you need a pure virtual function then?

Comment: no, the classType() function should be static member. and also B may have sub classes.

Comment: Then use the type traits instead of static members.

Comment: @Evg, could you please provide a sample using type traits?

Comment: See edited answer.

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, make `A::classType()` private in `B`:

```
class B : public A {
private:
    using A::classType;
}
```

**Edit.** After the question has been clarified, I suggest that you use type traits technique instead of static member functions.

```
template<class>
struct Traits;

template<>
struct Traits<A> {
    static const char* classType() {
        return "A";
    }
};

template<class T>
const char* TypeOf() {
    return Traits<T>::classType();
}
```

Now the user has to define his own type trait for `B`, otherwise

```
const char* type = TypeOf<B>();
```

will not compile.

Comment: Explicitly deleting the function in class `B` seems more expressive to me.  Both approaches work with classes inheriting from `B`.

Comment: @PaulSanders, agree. I upvoted your answer. But there is an alternative solution, nevertheless.

Answer (score 3):

Apart from a couple of typos in your code ... add the following to the definition of class `B`

```
static const char* classType() = delete;
```

[Live Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/acg9aBCMrvTdORiF)

Comment: It's not my purpose. My purpose is that when  the author forgets to write the classType() function in the sub classes of class A, the author should get a reminder.

Answer (score 1):

I got the idea from @Evg, thanks Evg.
Use template like below:

```
class A
{
public:
    template <class T>
    static const char* classType() { static_assert(false, "classType not implemented"); }
    template <>
    static const char* classType<A>()
    {
        static const char* s_classType = "A";
        return s_classType;
    }
};

template <class T>
const char* TypeOf()
{
    return T::classType<T>();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare the function as pure virtual.

```
class A
{
public:
    virtual static const char* classType() =0;
};
```

Then all instantiated classes inheriting from A have to implement this.